# Interactive matplotlib plots run slowly in pycharm console

Tags: python, matplotlib, pycharm

I am using the matplotlib FuncAnimation, and I found it works differently whether I run the code as a file or execute it in python console. If using python console, the animation will be noticeably slower to the point where it is almost useless. I am using pycharm and TkAgg interactive backend for matplotlib. How can I make the animation run smoothly when executing from console?

Here is an example animation from the matplotlib documentation. It's very simple so the speed issue doesn't actually matter here, but you can still easily notice the difference.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
t = np.linspace(0, 3, 40)
g = -9.81
v0 = 12
z = g * t**2 / 2 + v0 * t
v02 = 5
z2 = g * t**2 / 2 + v02 * t
scat = ax.scatter(t[0], z[0], c="b", s=5, label=f'v0 = {v0} m/s')
line2 = ax.plot(t[0], z2[0], label=f'v0 = {v02} m/s')[0]
ax.set(xlim=[0, 3], ylim=[-4, 10], xlabel='Time [s]', ylabel='Z [m]')
ax.legend()
def update(frame):
    # for each frame, update the data stored on each artist.
    x = t[:frame]
    y = z[:frame]
    # update the scatter plot:
    data = np.stack([x, y]).T
    scat.set_offsets(data)
    # update the line plot:
    line2.set_xdata(t[:frame])
    line2.set_ydata(z2[:frame])
    return (scat, line2)
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig=fig, func=update, frames=40, interval=30)
plt.show()
```